# How to inline compressed CSS in Rails with assets pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm trying to inline CSS into my layout. I'm currently using

> = Rails.application.assets.find_asset('embedded.css').body.html_safe

However, the CSS returned is **not compressed**. I verified what `.digest_path` asset file exists, and is properly compressed.

I can, of course, write a helper that will check if current on-disk compressed asset file exists for a given asset, and use it. However, I think find_asset actually compiles a CSS asset each time it is called -- not good in production. I hope a cleaner solution exists for this issue.

Comment: `find_asset` does have a caching mechanism built in (which lives in `tmp/cache/assets`). You can see it here: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/index.rb#L59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If assets are to be rebuilt in Production, production has to have access to minifiers. By default, Gemfile has something like this:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

Need to remove `:group assets do`, so these gems are included in production environment too. Then, `find_asset` rebuilds the asset and minimizes/compresses it on the first call, and caches it.

Comment: I tried your solution and I'm still getting uncompressed CSS